# How to Get sum() of single column values

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sum

I have bellow snippet table structure.In this table there is one row `count_set` that have two values first is `1` and second is `1` here i have to make the `sum` of this value the sum answer will be `2`.

[image: table]

I tried with bellow query but not getting sum value its getting sum with blank value.
so can any one tell me how to do this.

```
    $sql_chk_current_sum_count = "SELECT sum(count_set) FROM wp_lead_count WHERE       
    end_date = $end_date";
    $final_sum= $wpdb->get_results($sql_chk_current_sum_count) or   die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What is the output which you are getting with your query?

Comment: @RahulTripathi  its blank

Comment: What is the output of the query when executed directly in database? `SELECT sum(count_set) FROM wp_lead_count WHERE       
    end_date = '2015-10-30'`?

Comment: you only need sum of that particular column right?

Comment: what is the format of **$end_date** ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sum(count_set) FROM wp_lead_count WHERE       
    date_format(end_date,'%Y-%m-%d') = date_format($end_date,'%Y-%m-%d');
```